# Any good SIP library for C#?

Tags: c#, sip

Does anyone know if there is any good library around that can be used to easily build a SIP softphone?

Thanks in advance,

Cheers,
Gianluca.

Answer (score 1):

Konnetic provide fully managed SIP (and MSRP if you want messaging) components for .NET development. Their [.NET SIP](http://www.konnetic.com/products/products_sip_sdk_std.aspx) SDK is probably the most comprehensive and is aimed at clients.

Otherwise, Microsoft's Lync server comes with a very good managed SIP library, available here: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/default.aspx Although you are tied to Lync server.

If you want a stateless solution consider http://www.independentsoft.com/

There are a number of C# libraries that are wrappers around C++ libs eg. http://sites.google.com/site/sipekphone/pjsipwrapper uses pjSIP underneath.