# Implementing state aware sip proxy in C#

Tags: c#, sip

I need to implement a sip proxy in C#, I am beginner to C# and to sip.

I have found this library: [SIPSorcery](http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/) however it lacks documentation. Do you know any other, better projects that is well documented and suit my need?

Also are there any examples of how to register to a proxy, process calls, ... .

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051767/any-good-sip-library-for-c

Comment: I have read that thread however I didn't find there everything I need. It would be great if someone would provide an actual example of how to use that or that library, the basic register would be enought

Comment: Hmm that's annoying I meant to post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498056/c-sharp-sip-stack-library it's a bit more informative than the previous link and points to a nice implementation with lots of documentation http://www.iptel.org/ser/

Comment: I'm the sipsorcery author. TBH it's one of those projects that originally got open sourced to see if there was any interest but now it's mainly there for people to inspect and offer the occasional bug fix. It's not intended as a SIP SDK or API. There is already a SIP Proxy available in the project that utilises an IronRuby script to control SIP message routing (similar to the OpenSER's openser.cfg) it may suit your needs although it is a bit unclear exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

SIPSorcery is merely an experiment and as such I would not try to use it for anything serious... to quote a post by the sipsorcery developer...

"Need an example SIP client in C #.
I tried to deal with http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/ but little documentation I can not even make or receive calls.
Recommend anything?"

"Yes I'm notoriously bad with documentation, sorry.

More than likely the sipsorcery SIP client is not what you're after. It's a pure SIP implementation with no RTP or audio capabilities which means it's useless as far as a standalone VoIP client that you can use to make and receive calls WITH audio. In other words it can do the SIP signalling side of things but without the audio capabilities that's not much good for a client side application; the sipsorcery project is predominantly server side.

Of late I have been playing around a bit with NAudio with the goal of adding a very rudimentary audio capability to the softphone example but I've no idea when I'll have something working."

Take a look at http://www.iptel.org/ser/ for a good / fuller project with lots of documentation.

Comment: well thanks, I actually need a server side library, after all I'm going to do a sip proxy. If you or anybody else know some point where to start please show me. Any code snippet or what class/methods can I use to receive packet, inspect it, send, forward, create ... .

Comment: If you don't want to build it from scratch - which doesn't seem advisable if you don't understand SIP with regards to the proxy, client, softphone etc I would advise using a third party API akin to http://www.independentsoft.com/sip/index.html (299 euros at time of writing), they have some nice code samples / documentation.

Comment: I have been talking to them and they said that it is not a good choice for what I need

Comment: Download and take a look at http://www.lumisoft.ee/lswww/download/downloads/Net/ for some ideas on c# sip stack and proxy

Comment: Thanks, it looks like too high level for me. I need to have control over the messages.

Comment: I think that I will use SIPSorcery after all, thanks Paul Zahra for your help. Do you know the SIPSorcery? If yes, can you please guide me how to receive, send, parse, create ... request and respond, what classed I should use.